# Get IP from DNS

Tags: c#, tcp, dns, udp

How can I create a stream of data to find the IP of a certain domain using TCP?
Searching around the forum and tried something like this:

```
client = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"), 53);
client.Connect(ep);
String query = "host -T google.com";
byte[] myByte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(query);
client.Send(myByte, myByte.Length);
var receivedData = client.Receive(ref ep);
```

I don't understand how to create the correct message for DNS server. If something similar to the HTTP way exist, it would be great.

**UPDATE: This is how you do it!**

```
    client = new UdpClient();
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"), 53);
    client.Connect(ep);

    //dynamic dns
    String host1 = "vg.no";
    byte[] hostnameLength = new byte[1];
    byte[] hostdomainLength = new byte[1];


    byte[] tranactionID1 = { 0x46, 0x62 };
    byte[] queryType1 = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    byte[] hostname = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(host1.Split('.')[0]);
    hostnameLength[0] = (byte)hostname.Length;
    byte[] hostdomain = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(host1.Split('.')[1]);
    hostdomainLength[0] = (byte)hostdomain.Length;
    byte[] queryEnd = {0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01};
    byte[] dnsQueryString = tranactionID1.Concat(queryType1).Concat(hostnameLength).Concat(hostname).Concat(hostdomainLength).Concat(hostdomain).Concat(queryEnd).ToArray();
    client.Send(dnsQueryString, dnsQueryString.Length);
```

Comment: A http server has a service running on either port 80 or 8080 that gets started when computer is turned on.  TCP you need to write your own application to receive on port 53.  See examples on following webpage.  A Listener application runs on the server : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx.  The examples are for sockets but will also work for any class that inherits sockets like tcpclient and tcplistener.

Comment: do you need to use low level TCP messages ?

Comment: @jdweng DNS servers don't run on 80 or 8080 as they aren't http services. Looks like what the OP wants to do is to query a DNS server to get the IP for a host (that isn't the DNS server).

Comment: Yes i need to do this at a low level. As low as possible.Yes i would like to query some kind of DNS to get IP for host. I entered the google dns 8.8.8.8. So i can't use the client reponse to "wait for the answer? I have to write the server in the same application to listen for the dns answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is simply "Get IP of domain from DNS in C#" the simple answer is

```
var res = Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com").AddressList;
```

This statement return a string array with IP addresses of resolved domain name.

If the question is more complex "Get IP of domain from DNS in C# using TCP/IP protocol", take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227863/dns-lookup-from-custom-dns-server-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The latter. I would like to know how to use TCP/IP to find the IP address for a certain domain. I cant depend the code base for only C#.